# Pyrex glass coffee pot

Tags: equipment, kitchen-safety

I have a very old Pyrex glass coffee pot that belonged to my grandmother.   As a kid, I have a distant memory of her using it on a gas stove to boil water.  The pot has a picture of a flame on the bottom of it, but it doesn't say either way whether it's safe to use on a gas stove.   I'm sure the pot is very old;  maybe 1950s or 60s.  Any advice?

Comment: Hi Carol, welcome to the site. I think some pictures would be useful in order to answer your question.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54298/pyrex-percolator-on-stove/54302#54302

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like what you have is Pyrex Flameware, which is range safe.

From the [link](http://www.ndga.net/articles/gmflameware.php):

> Flameware by Pyrex by Corning Glass Works of Corning, New York is a line of range top kitchenware...
>
> Identification of Flameware is easy as most pieces were imprinted in the bottom of each piece with the "flame" logo, plus the item number and size.

Comment: Thanx 4 the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I have two Pyrex coffee pots that sound like they are the same as this. If they are Flameware, they are made for use on a stove top. I love mine.

Comment: Thanx 4 the advice!